# GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent() won't due for termination signaling to process run by cmd.exe

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, cmd, signals

When one is interactively using `cmd.exe` to run all sort of windows CLI application, one can easily stop them by pressing `CTRL+C` or `CTRL+BREAK` . this is implemented by signaling the process as can be read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As for `cmd.exe` itself, it does not terminate in these conditions as can be explained in a comment of this [question](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Now, consider the following scenario. My application open a `cmd.exe` using `CreateProcess()`, and the user has started another application `b.exe`  through it. Say that my application want to fold before `b.exe` has ended , and it doesn't really care about the graceful termination of it. optimally, I'd like to mimic the user pressing `CTRL+C` and then send `exit` to the `cmd.exe` (let's say I can do it IO-wise). the windows api offers [GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683155%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for that (almost) exact purpose, but it can be ignored by the process (`cmd.exe` in that case) and in particular , it won't forward the signal to `b.exe`.

Comment: CreateJobObject + AssignProcessToJobObject + TerminateJobObject.

Comment: @HansPassant whats guarantee that a sub-process created by `cmd.exe` or one of his children will be assigned to the job?

Comment: A good one, breaking away from a job takes work.

Comment: @HansPassant ok, reading the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161(v=vs.85).aspx) clarified my gap, as it turns out that -  "**After a process is associated with a job, by default any child processes it creates using CreateProcess are also associated with the job.**"